# "В радиусе ста метров"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее: "В радиусе ста метров" или "В радиусе сто метров"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В радиусе чего? Нужен родительный падеж. Замените слово "сто" на слово "сотня": *в радиусе сотни метров*. Соответственно, *в радиусе ста метров*.

Answer (score 0):

Как отдельное слово "сто" склоняется по падежам, но оно не изменяется в составе сложных слов, например: нет стопятидесятилетия, стодвадцатилетний и т.п.