# Почему не склоняется "сто" в составе сложных слов?

Tags: словообразование, склонение, сложные-слова

Как склоняется слово *сто*, очень хорошо отметил Валентин в [этом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5252/%D0%92-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/5326#5326) вопросе:

> Как отдельное слово "сто" склоняется по падежам, но оно не изменяется в составе сложных слов, например: нет стопятидесятилетия, стодвадцатилетний и т. п.

***Только вот почему оно не склоняется?*** Неприятно запоминать правило, не понимая, почему так странно сложилось. Например, *пятидесятитысячный, **но** стотысячный.* Странно.

Answer (score 1):

В исключение слово попало, потому что оно воспринималось не так, как все остальные числительные. Заметили, что у него даже парадигма склонения неполная - только две формы?

Все числительные в древнерусском языке - счётные слова: существительные или прилагательные. Сто - существительное и как склонялось как существительное, так и вошло  в сложные числительные: трёмстам, о трёхстах, но дальнейший процесс нумерализации привёл к тому, что синтаксические связи его изменились. Слово "сто" в значении существительного (сотня) употребляется теперь только в косв. пад. мн. ч. обычно в сочетании с числ. много и несколько: род. п. сот (несколько сот рублей), дат. п. стам (нескольким стам рублей), тв. п. стами (редко: с несколькими стами рублей), предл. п. о стах (Напечатано много сведений о нескольких стах деятелей. И. Грабарь). Встречающиеся сочетания типа в нескольких стах письмах (газ.); в нескольких стах метрах (Симон.), в которых сто не управляет существительным, а согласуется с ним в падеже (т. е. выступает как числительное), не нормативны. В подобных случаях рекомендуется употреблять формы сущ. сотня: в нескольких сотнях писем, в нескольких сотнях метров.

Числовое значение как название восходит к индоевропейскому СТО, которое является формой ед. ч. им.-вин. пад. сущ. с собират. значением "сто" = "десять десятков". Г.П.Цыганенко считает, что в индоевр. корне "десять" содержится греч. корень "дека".(Ссылку на словарь пыталась найти, не получилось, видимо, связано с тем, что Галина Павловна - украинский автор, хоть и советских времён. У меня бумажный носитель 1989 года. Но у Фасмера тоже есть указание на этот корень: " Пизани объясняет *sъto из *k̂u-tom от *dk̂u-to-, ступени редукции *dek̂u- «десять»; ср. лат. decu-ria, гот. tigjus «десять»; https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D1%81/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE") Вот мы и добрались до сути: СТО-это **застывшая форма им. и вин. пад**., поэтому у него только две формы - сто и ста (а - отголосок множ.-двойств. ч.).

Вот ещё интересный научно-популярный материал http://proza.ru/2012/01/05/1001

А вот в состав сложных слов оно входит **на правах иноязычных первых частей как несклоняемое - застывшая форма им. пад.** Хотя когда-то была и склоняемая форма родительного, теперь это ненормированное, просторечное - "стаголосый хор", но в худ. литературе иногда встречается для стилизации.

Девяносто - тоже неясное происхождение, там формы девяносто-девяноста закрепились по подобию со словом "сто".

Comment: Людмила, а как бы  Вы ответили на вопрос: почему при наличии формы СТА, которая соответствует всем косвенным падежам, в том числе и Р.п., всё-таки в сложных словах стала употребляться начальная форма, а склоняемая форма СТА (как в слове стаголосый)  так и не утвердилась?

Comment: Склоняемая форма употребляется как просторечие - теми, кто не знает об иноязычном происхождении слова "сто" и использует его как русское. Все сложные слова появились не так давно, когда наука уже обладала достаточными знаниями о происхождении числительных, зачем же составителям словарей ориентироваться на "незнающих"?

Comment: Но, кажется, "сто" не считают иноязычным словом. Из словаря: СТО, возникновение 9 -11 вв, от праславянского из древнерусского съто, сотьница - сотня. о.- с. основа sъtо, сотый, сотня - в словаре с 1704 года.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Ещё не дочитал, уже вопрос: "в нескольких стах метров (если поменяем падеж)" — ненормативно, а "о нескольких стах деятелей" — нормативно? Или неномативно только из за падежа (метрАХ)? Если кто-то понял мысль, тоже просьба объяснить.

Comment: Всё, я понял: там есть "несколько", а тут нету.

Comment: «В индоевр. корне "десять" содержится греч. корень "дека"» — что, простите?.. В индоевропейском корне (*[d]k’mtom) не содержится никаких греческих корней )) Думаю, вам стоит переформулировать предложение.

Comment: «А вот в состав сложных слов оно входит на правах иноязычных первых частей как несклоняемое - застывшая форма им. пад.» — и откуда заимствовали-то? Будьте добры, дайте ссылку на исследование. По-моему, тут никакими иноязычными частями и не пахнет.

Comment: Jasmin, Вы не дочитали статью из словаря, дальше там написано: Древнерусское «съто» заимствовано из старославянского, где восходит к общеславянскому sъto (сто, сотня) и далее – к индоевропейскому k´mtom<(d)k´mtom от dek´m (десять).

Comment: Если до конца дочитать статью из словаря Фасмера, то  и там говорится, что нет общепринятой теории происхождения, разные учёные выдвигают разные версии, Крылов пишет: "Праславянское индоевропейской природы" . Фасмер в конце статьи  приводит версию Пизани:  Пизани объясняет *sъto из *k̂u-tom от *dk̂u-to-, ступени редукции *dek̂u- «десять»; ср. лат. decu-ria, гот. tigjus «десять»; https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D1%81/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE

Comment: Людмила, но все же: как, право, в праиндоевропейском может быть греческий корень? Все же наоборот: в греческом нашел отражение и.-е. корень...

Comment: Я же не говорю об очерёдности - что из чего пришло, я говорю, что по звучанию-дека- это именно греческий корень, а не русский, по крайней мере, от него в русском слово декада - десятидневка, оно проникло к нам из французского, этот же корень в лат.decem, а у нас от него дециметр. Почему же декада, дециметр - заимствования, а  *[d]k’mtom (дэкм) - десять - русское?

Comment: По своему происхождению лексика современного русского языка разделяется на две группы: исконную и заимствованную.Исконная лексика подразделяется на следующие группы: общеиндоевропейскую,  общеславянскую, восточнославянскую (древнерусскую), собственно русскую с конца XV века. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лексика_русского_языка  Слово «сто» относится к общеславянской лексике и поэтому является исконно русским словом.

Comment: Во-первых, к этой статье по Вашей ссылке есть замечание "Эта статья должна быть полностью переписана", во-вторых, там нет слова сто, в-третьих, речь идёт о характеристике индоевропейского корня и процессах его освоения в русском, чего Вы не хотите понять. Сам облик слова сто тождествен несклоняемому или сущ. среднего рода, а такие слова в сложных прилагательных тоже несклоняемы, они обозначают признак предмета, обусловленный числом сто, здесь нет соединительной гласной, это застывшая форма.

Answer (score 0):

**Это тема сложных слов, у которых в качестве первой основы используются числительные.**

По правилу такие сложные слова делятся **на группы**.

Для большинства числительных используется **форма Р. п.**: двадцатипятилетие, сорокаметровый.

Но есть исключения. Это числительные:
**1) сто, девяносто;

2) тысяча, миллион;

3) сорок, два, три.**

В группе 1 используется начальная форма (**она как бы соответствует соединительной гласной О**); в группе 2 — соединительная гласная О/Е, **как для обычных существительных**; в группе 3 — разные варианты (сорокалетие, но сороконожка; формы ДВУ- и ДВУХ-, ТРЕХ-, ТРИ , ТРЕ-).

https://sci.house/russkiy-yazyik-scibook/pravopisanie-slojnyih-slov-76770.html

Comment: _Артём Луговой: Спасибо!_ === ЧуднО!!! Артём, а Вы помните, КАКОЙ именно вопрос Вы задавали? Вы на НЕГО получили ответ? Напомню Ваше: _"Как склоняется слово **сто**, очень хорошо отметил Валентин... Только вот почему оно не склоняется? **Неприятно запоминать правило, не понимая, почему так странно сложилось".**_  Получается, теперь поняли, откуда ноги растут у этого правила?

Comment: По-моему вопрос звучит так: почему числительное "сто" не склоняется в составе сложных слов. Ответ: это исключение,  в словах "столетие, пятидесятилетие"  и др. окончание О соотносится с соединительной гласной О.

Comment: _**Неприятно запоминать правило, не понимая, почему так странно сложилось**._ === Это не я придумал. Это из вопроса Артёма. А Вы просто воспроизвели в своём ответе это правило. Потому я и изумился "спасибо" Артёма.

Comment: Почему мы не пишем "сталетие"? Может быть, это какое-то недоразумение: если родительный падеж, то пусть везде будет родительный падеж.  Но мне вот кажется, что в этом "сталетии" число "сто" не сразу узнаешь. Возможно, и другим так показалось, вот и попало слово в исключения. Как говорится, не всегда получается    всех стричь  под одну гребенку.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71259/discussion-on-answer-by-jasmin--------).